# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/xyz' by 3 commits

Tags: git

I am working on a remote branch.I just tried doing git status and it shows your branch is ahead of 'origin/xyz' by 3 commits .
What it does mean and how do I resolve this issue ?
Being a newbie  to version control, I find git bit intimidating when it comes to branches.
Note:xyz is the remote branch .

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Probably it is better to first get at least a working knowledge of the git before using it in real-life situations so that you don't break things unintentionally. I would say that https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 is a good start.

Comment: I need to understand as how to get rid of this message where my branch is haed of 'origin/xyz'.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of this message?  There is nothing wrong at all about it.

Comment: I didn't know that the message is not wrong. I felt that i did something wrong my branch and need to resest head or something .

Comment: That is why I said that you should first read the basics. IMHO, it is dangerous to use VC without knowing the basics, you might lose your precious work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Your+branch+is+ahead

Answer (score 1):

The message coming from `git status` is simply telling you that your local branch `xyz` has three new commits as compared to the tracking branch `origin/xyz`.  The tracking branch is a snapshot of what the true remote branch `xyz` looked like, at the time when you last synched with a `git pull`.  In more common language, you have made three new commits, but the remote does not yet "know" about them.

As for what you should do, you don't necessarily have to do anything.  You could push those commits to the remote branch.  But, you might want to first do a `git pull` to bring in any new other commits which others might have made.

Comment: Should i be doing git pull origin xyz?